# Como funciona app híbrido que corre em Node.js?

Tags: node.js, app, back-end

Como funciona a questão do back-end com Node.js numa app mobile?

É possível usar o serviço Phonegap Build que compila minha aplicação para a plataforma desejada (Android ou iOS por exemplo). Mas como fica a questão do Node.js, pois é preciso hospedá-lo certo? Como ficaria isso?

Comment: Você está misturando os conceitos. Explique melhor o que quer fazer antes de decidir qual arquitetura quer.

Comment: @PabloAlmeida eu estou construindo um app híbrido e uso o node para o back-end. Quando meu app for compilado ele vai rodar em uma WebView, certo? O que quero entender é como o node vai rodar se ele precisa ser hospedado afinal é um servidor